# Is it possible to run an IIS site as a logged in user?

Tags: iis, .net-core, user32

I'm experimenting with running a .NET Core site in IIS as my own logged in user, because I have written an API that interacts with `User32.Dll` (moves cursor for example).

I don't care about the security aspect of running a website as my own user.

If I set up the site completely normal in IIS (with identity set to ApplicationPoolIdentity), the API starts and everything works, except it's not my user it's trying to interact with.

At this point I've managed to set the identity to DOMAIN\USER (my user), but when I try to start the application pool, it dies (stops) when I send the first request and just returns 503 service unavailable.

I was hoping running an IIS site as my own local user would be easy, but I've spent probably 2 hours now trying to get it to work. What steps do I have to take? I'm quite lost at this point.

EDIT: I should probably mention, that when I start the application pool, w3wp.exe is not being run. So something is definitely wrong, when I try with my own user as the identity.

Comment: You can take a look at Granting Folder Permissions on this page to grant your folder permissions: https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Best-Adv-Install-Using-a-Service-Account-to-Run-IIS-App-Pool-and-SQL-DB

Comment: You can of course care nothing about security, but Windows/IIS is not designed as you wished, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 Session isolation alone prevents the code running on IIS to gain access to the logon user's session and desktop, so moving a cursor by calling a User32 API is impossible. There are workarounds, but none is simple.